# Need a regex for the following expression?

Tags: regex, perl

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

$str = "ab_cde,efg_gh,drg_fgt,main_xx,sum(abc),avg(def)";
```

or

```
$str = "ab_cde,bc_bn,gy_ihf,efg_gh,drg_fgt,main_xx,sum(abc),avg(def‌​)";
```

Guys, the string before `main_xx` is dynamic means there can be more elements with this format like `xx_xx` or `xxx_xx` or `xx_xxx` or `xxx_xxxx` or it can be as many characters before and after "underscore". So before `main_xx`, as many elements can come with above format. I want to match string UP TO main_xx`because even fetching dynamically, this "main_xx" will be the last element and want to ignore elements after`main_xx`. Please help to create a regex for this.

Comment: Can you add few more example inputs with your expected matches?

Comment: Please edit your question and add it

Comment: So, i want to match whole string before main_xx whatever be the no. of elements come and ignore any thing after main_xx.

Comment: @yonyon100 edited.

Comment: @anubhava, i need to include "main_xx" also. with this, only values before  main_xx are coming.

Comment: ok then `/(.*,main_[^,]*)/` should work.

Comment: @anubhava The character should be `xx` then why you negate it `[^,]+`?

Comment: `[^,]+` allows `xx` to be a dynamic value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $str = "ab_cde,efg_gh,drg_fgt,main_xx,sum(abc),avg(def)";
(my $result) = ($str =~ m/(.*main_xx)/);
print $result;
```

The output will be everything up to `main_xx` (given `xx` is just the string made of x's).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
my $str = "ab_cde,efg_gh,drg_fgt,main_xx,sum(abc),avg(def)";
my ($match)= $str =~m/(.+main_xx)/;
print $match;
```